# Mathematical error in reputation addition

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

I have 312 reputation and two of my edits approved.
So my reputation change have to be 312+2+2=316.
But it is showing 315.

I know 1 reputation is not a big deal at all but I want to know that is there any specific reason for this or a bug.

I have even checked removed post too but its not showing anything.

Comment: As usual: What does [the reputation audit page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation) tell you?

Comment: @Bobby thanx for the fast help but this cap is showing that my repo is previously 311 but thats not true.

Comment: No, that reputation page *is the measure of all things*. If that page *would* be wrong, that would be a serious flaw. It's more likely that that one reputation point is some delete/undelete/migration magic which is is not tracked (but instead changes the history).

Comment: What is the reason for downvote now after 8  days.

Comment: @jas - probably the same reason for the first 3 downvotes...   Voting on meta is not always about the quality of your question.

Comment: @Lix when i stared this question it got up/downvotes and in end it shows -1 votes because it have one more downvote then upvote but why today it got three more downvote after 8 days.

Comment: @jas - It was pushed to the front page from your recent edits.  On meta, incoming posts are not as frequent as on the main site - so your post gets more attention here - hence the scrutiny...

Comment: @Lix ok, thanx for help.

Comment: Also, those very edits *seemed* to have been done just to get some attention. That might have caused some downvotes too? (Don't know for sure; I didn't vote but I somehow was tempted to, after seeing that edit...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a post got deleted or something.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1311977/jason-vorhees?tab=reputation&sort=post

When I add up the per-day rep, it's fine. That means that some deleted post/migration/whatever has been calculated.

Check the "show deleted posts" thingy at the bottom of the page to see what may have been eaten up by the system.

You can see another rep counter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: +1 for quick response but i have mentioned in question that "show delete post" not helping and i have checked it fully but their is no new deduction of reputation for -1 and the rep counter is showing that my rep is 311 before edit approvals but its 312 at that movement.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees: Well, to me it all adds up to 315, but I don't have access to deleted posts so those are missing entirely. Probably a bug then :/